# controller and factory calling sequence differs while using $http?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a simple login, so I just created a html page with username and password. I created a controller and called a function called login and inside that I called a factory which returns a factory data, and I would create login based on that data.

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('login', ['$scope','$rootScope', '$location', '$window', 'authenticate', '$http', '$cookieStore',function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $window, authenticate, $http, $cookieStore) {
$scope.alert = '';
$scope.login = function(){
    authenticate.login($scope.login.username, $scope.login.password).then(function(response){
        alert("Inside controller"+JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
}]);
```

**My factory**

```
myApp.factory('authenticate',['$http', '$filter', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$window', '$q',
function($http, $filter, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $window, $q) {
    var data = "";
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return {
        login: function(userName,password){
            $http.post('user/serverside/authentication.php',{username: userName, password: password})
            .then(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
                alert("FACTORY"+JSON.stringify(response));
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

I call the login function inside the controller on login, 
The issue is when I logged in for

- The first time with one data as expected first alert inside factory
  executed and then the alert inside the controller is executed.
- But on the second time alert inside controller executed first and the
  factory alert displaying,

**Doubts**

1. Why the execution sequence change in the second time?
2. Is this a right way to use for login, if any better ways please
   suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mistake its beacuse u should generate promise in every function and no in the main factory like:

```
myApp.factory('authenticate',['$http', '$filter', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$window', '$q',
function($http, $filter, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $window, $q) {
    var data = "";

    return {
        login: function(userName,password){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post('user/serverside/authentication.php',{username: userName, password: password})
            .then(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
                alert("FACTORY"+JSON.stringify(response));
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Ur code not works because promise its generated first time executed and when code checked if promise its resolve automatically execute then block.

2.- You can use ssl to securize your login, but the function login its similar. The important its implementation its on server side.

Comment: Thanks Javie. Let me try your idea once and I will come back to you.

Comment: Thanks javie, Its work I can handle serverside things. 
Can you pls tell me this 2 things?
How placing this defer(), works?Can you explain little briefer with a plunker or text?
Any ways to do encrypted authentication?

Comment: Hi abel, u question about why works when placing defer() inside function this works? and to encryted authentication the best way is use SSL(https) in your site.